# How to translate Package overview url to apt-add-repository command

Tags: apt, package-management

I guess that is a real noob question, but how can I translate such a package overview like that:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/openbox

into an appropriate `sudo apt-add-repository` command ??

I am on a freshly install ubuntu 18.04 server an I like to install that package.

Thanks for help!

Comment: try this https://launchpad.net/~k-belding/+archive/ubuntu/ppa or this https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/openbox/download sir

Comment: Though you linked to the 16.04 package, the same package in 18.04 is also in universe. Enable universe and install.

Comment: Well yes, adding universe solved it, but how do I generally know how to translate those url into a suitable entry in `sources.list` ??

Comment: @philipp generally, you don't go about adding repositories for a different release. For the same release, see if the package is labeled `[universe]`, `[restricted]` or `[multiverse]` and use those instead of `universe` in the commands from the linked post.

Comment: @muru Welcome back.  Please drop by in Chat?